# How to swap first and last DOM elements

Tags: javascript, dom

How to swap for example the first list item with last list item without jquery.

```
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

My code so far:

```
var ul = document.querySelector("ul"),
    first = ul.firstElementChild,
    last = ul.lastElementChild;
ul.replaceChild(first,last);
```

The jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v3b0qmnz/

Comment: Check this out http://www.w3.org/TR/ElementTraversal/#attribute-previousElementSibling you can use different javascript elements such as firstelementchild and lastelementchild

Comment: What have you found out and tried so far?

Comment: Nothing, I tried repalaceChild method but no luck with it!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/v3b0qmnz/ can you tell me what is wrong with this.

Comment: *"can you tell me what is wrong with this."* There is nothing "wrong" with it. It's just incomplete. You are not putting the last element in front.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update:
if you want swap, then follow this: http://jsfiddle.net/7uppg0zg/1/

```
    var ul = document.getElementById("ul")
    var last = ul.lastElementChild
    var first = ul.firstElementChild
    ul.replaceChild(ul.firstElementChild, ul.lastElementChild)
    ul.insertBefore(last, ul.firstElementChild)
```

Note:
replaceChild: first argument is the one that you want to replace with and second one is the one that you want to be replaced.
ref: http://www.w3schools.com/dom/met_node_replacechild.asp

Comment: but where is the first list item gone?

Comment: Providing an **explanation** and not just code is much more valuable.